# Android, прыгает картинка при появлении экранной клавиатуры

Tags: xml, android, android-scrollview

Доброго времени суток. 
Имеем такой XML файл, при тапе на edit появляется клавиатура и картинка прыгает в верх, предположительно из-за ScrollView. Как решить эту проблему?

<
ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <requestFocus />
    </ImageView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_login"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#E5E4E2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:hint="@string/username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pass"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#E5E4E2"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textWebPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_login"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_guest"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_login"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="@string/guest"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_text"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/loading_data" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

</ScrollView>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

В нужную активити в AndroidManifest.xml